# copying database and website folders on wampserver

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I had installed my wampserver on Local Disk D. Yesterday because my machine was infected with virus I had to format it. Since I would format Local disk C and not D I did not see the need to backup my website and database as they would be available on D and once I needed the project I would just copy paste as I have been doing for sometime. After formatting, I copied the database from the previous wamp data folder **D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data\database_name** to my new installation **C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data\database_name**. I did the same to my website i.e. from **D:\wamp\www\website** to  **C:\wamp\www\website**. However, the project seems not to work as it was working on the previous installation. What am I missing or are there other files I need to copy?

Comment: Rule of thumb: a backup is something one does on a regular base _before_ issues arise...

Comment: Apart from that we cannot really offer any help with that vague and little information you offer... No error messages, nothing specific about what "seems not to work" actually means... Sorry.

Comment: One thing though... why do you have to move that data anyway? Why don't you continue using that second partition in the new installation?

Comment: @arkascha yes not backing up was a mistake. and how do I run from the first installation I thought after formatting C old wampserver executable files would be deleted

Comment: Certainly you have to reinstall the software, but that has little to do with the runtime data that software uses. I have little experience with your specific setup, but all the components should allow to configure whatever data folder you want.

Comment: @arkascha Its simple as long as the folders containing the old install still exist undamaged. WAMPServer only really ___installs___ the MYSQL and Apache services and they are simple to reinstall, so a full re-install is not necesary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the old WAMPServer was installed on the D: drive and you did not format that drive, then you can just reinstall the Apache and MYSQL services from there.

I would remove the new install (uninstall) and then do this

Make a shortcut of `D:\wamp\wampmanager.exe` and and place it on your desktop.

Launch WAMPServer from this new shortcut.

Using the wampmanager menus do

```
left click wampmanager icon -> MYSQL -> Services -> Install Service

left click wampmanager icon -> Apache -> Services -> Install Service
```

WAMPServer should be back as it was originally.

If you are using WAMPServer 3 > the menu items names changed a little to

```
left click wampmanager icon -> MYSQL -> Service Administration -> Install Service

left click wampmanager icon -> Apache -> Service Administration -> Install Service
```

Comment: this saved my alot of time, Thank you! @riggsfolly